# Mongoose schema model returning empty array using Model.find() in docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, docker, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB to provide data for my app via `node` and `mongoose`. I have created a schema for a `model` called `ReportSchema`, then I import the `model` to use it as `Report` for server request like `Report.find()`. I have also created some data in `MongoDB` via a database called `reports`, and everything works well in the MongoDB. But I get an empty array instead of the data I created. I have looked at other SO answers but none of them work, like changing the collection name, pluralise, etc.

I'm doing all of this through a docker container as a service.

I don't know whether I'm missing something in `docker`, `mongoose` or `node`. Please, can someone give me some guidance?

Thanks!

**MongoDB shell**

```
use reports

db.reports.insert({
  stepName: 'Step one',
  stepType: 'Milestone',
  description: 'Some phase to complete.',
  addToReport: false,
  date: new Date(),
});
```

**Mongoose Schema**

```
import { Schema, Document, model } from 'mongoose';

export interface Report extends Document {
  stepName: string;
  stepType: string;
  description: string;
  addToReport: boolean;
  date: Date;
}

export const ReportSchema = new Schema(
  {
    stepName: String,
    stepType: String,
    description: String,
    addToReport: Boolean,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export default model<Report>('report', ReportSchema, 'reports');
```

**Node**

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import Report from '../db/models';
import connection from './connection';

const app: Express = express();

const PORT: string | number = process.env.PORT || 7004;
const DB_NAME: string = 'reports';
const DB_URI: string = `mongodb://root:password@mongodb-service:27017/${DB_NAME}?authSource=admin`;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// GET reports
app.get('/reports', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const reports = await Report.find(); // --> this returns empty array, even though data exist.
    res.status(200).json({ reports });
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ error, errormessage: 'Error fetching reports!' });
  }
});

app.use(cors());

const connection = async (app: Express): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(DB_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    await app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Reporrs app running on port ${PORT}.`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('DB_CONN_ERROR:::' + error);
  }
};

// connection to mongo with mongoose
connection(app);
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12
COPY . /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN yarn
CMD yarn watch
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  reports-service:
    build: './reports-service'
    ports:
      - 7004:7004
    volumes:
      - ./reports-service:/opt/app

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `const reports = await Report.find({}).exec();`

Comment: The `map` is completely redundant and only ads to complexity. `res.status(200).json({ reports });` will cast them to POJOs anyway.

Comment: Good to know. I'll update my answer to exclude it.

Comment: Another way to convert the docs to plain objects is `Report.find().lean()`

Comment: Thanks @cseitz, but even with your solution, I still get an empty array. Also connection seems to fine, but I'm not sure if the issue is with the way my Dockerfile and docker-compse are setup; or maybe I'm not referencing the collection properly. Do you have any idea?

Comment: So its an empty array? Are you absolutely sure you have documents in your database? You should download `Mongodb Compass`, it lets you easily view your databases from an interface. Perhaps when you start the container its not loading up your previous databases entries?

Comment: The documents do exist in the database, I can see them. But for some reason, nothing wants to come out of the database, that's why I mentioned that maybe it's something to do with docker, or even with the mongoose model. I have also downloaded the MongoDB Compass and it doesn't wanna connect. It says `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb-service`.  I have no idea! The URI is `mongodb://root:password@mongodb-service:27017/reports?authSource=admin`. Again I'm not sure where I messed up.

Comment: You can not use ```mongodb-service:27017``` if you want to use Compass. This only works for a connection to something in the same docker network. Use ```localhost:27017``` instead

Comment: @Chai, ah ok, thanks! The thing is, I'm trying to access mongodb created in a docker container as a service. So my question is, how do I do it? Is it something in the dockerfile/docker-compose that I need to fix, is it the uri, is it the mongoose model, is it in node, etc?

Comment: it looks good to me, and since you do not get any connection refused errors and such I think that is working fine. That is why people ask you to make sure that it REALLY has the records.

Comment: @Chai, and I replied saying I can see the data that I've created in the database. When I do `db.reports.find()` in mongo shell, I do get the data. So it's weird to me that on the browser or Postman, I get an empty array. Bear in mind that my `mongodb` is in a `docker` container called `mongodb-service` not my `localhost`. So I think there's something that I have to do in `docker`, but again I'm not sure.

Comment: No it is running on localhost, docker just has a convenience way to connect to it from another docker inside the same network. I do notice one strange thing though, but I doubt it would be your problem.  In  compose file you specify a bind mount: ```mongodb_data_container:/data/db``` this creates a mapping between the docker container at ```/data/db``` to the directory ```mongodb_data_container``` . That might not always go well on every system. Change it to ```./mongodb_data_container:/data/db``` and remove the volume specification at the bottom since it is not being used.